# Riddle me this, birdman

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge, story, geography

I wanted to write a riddle in the form of a story, so here we are. Hope you like it.

> This is the story of great birds, two.
>   Around and around in the sky, they flew.
>   One remained small, while the other grew,
>   Till they looked like a sparrow, sat on a yew.
>
> The great one went up into the sky,
>   Nearly reaching the sun, it was ever so high.
>   The heat increased, making the great one cry,
>   As it saw its feathers fall off and die.
>
> With a screech of pain, the great one flew to the ground,
>   And struck the floor with an almighty sound.
>   The great one lay there all heaped in a mound,
>   As the small one landed and perched on its bare crown.
>
> Unfortunately for the small one, it found its own plight,
>   as the residue heat from the great bird had set it alight.
>   The flames swallowed it up, they burnt so bright.
>   Then from the ashes, a baby burst out into the daylight.
>
> This story of great birds, two,
>   tell of a place, but will you,
>   tell me where? I bet you do.
>   I have utmost faith in you.

Comment: That second stanza got quite dark lol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This was originally posted as a mostly-joking answer, but turned out to be correct! Thanks to OP and Chris Qu in comments for clarifying some things; the text below reflects my current understanding of how it's intended to work.]

The place is

> Phoenix, Arizona. (Or perhaps one of the other towns called Phoenix in the USA, but the one in Arizona is the best known.)

The first bird is

> an eagle, symbol of the United States.

The business about flying too high, losing feathers, etc.,

> is simply a way to make it a *bald* eagle, more specific symbol of the United States. There is no particular symbolism to the way in which it loses its feathers, and presumably we should *not* understand it to have died.

The second bird is

> a phoenix, bursting into flames and then emerging reborn from the ashes. Again, no particular symbolism to the fact that it catches fire *from the residual heat of the first bird*, nor to the business at the start where the first bird *grows* while the second doesn't.

Comment: That's actually, correct, but can you tell me why? And how does the other bird come into it?

Comment: I thought of the same place ;)

Comment: Huh, interesting. I wouldn't have guessed more than a 10% chance of its being right. Let me do some digging and see if I can figure out why :-).

Comment: (I mean, something something Hohokam something something O'odham something, but what little I can find out about their history doesn't seem like it matches well enough with the given text to make a satisfying answer.)

Comment: Well the most obvious reference is to how a phoenix is reborn from it's ashes.

Comment: Of course, and that's why the city is called what it is. But I assume we're looking for a closer and more detailed correspondence than that.

Comment: Alas, none of this was intended :P You've discovered what one of the birds is, the identity of the other bird then leads to the answer you first gave. The story itself is just one I made up to give the birds descriptors (and how they got them) to help identify the type of bird.

Comment: (Surely there are *three* birds here: the big one, the little one, and the finally-emergent baby.)

Comment: Due to the identity of the small bird, the implication is that the small bird and baby are one and the same.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I was looking for a connection between your answer and Icarus, which is what I believe the bigger bird was...not sure if this helps at all....

Comment: @El-Guest I'm afraid it's not Icarus (although in hindsight it unintentionally is similar to that story) Think about a descriptor for the other bird (before the phoenix part happens)

Comment: As stated by Gareth, the answer is Phoenix, Arizona. My contribution is the guess that the larger bird is an Eagle. And after its feathers fall off, and the smaller bird lands on its bare crown, it is a *bald* eagle. If we take this as a symbol of America, we have a city and a country. There are a handful of cities called that in the United States, though. I'm not sure there is any way to conclude that it must be Arizona...

Comment: [Chris's comment above was posted as an answer, prefaced with "I wish I were able to comment, but this account is new and I lack the reputation". Your wish is our command, Chris! I've made it into a comment.]

Comment: You could certainly be right about the eagle. If so, it seems like most of the content of the poem is merely "filler". And, as you say, there are other cities with the same name...

Comment: I can't believe OP didn't even think of Icarus while writing this!

Comment: @ChrisQu is correct! I am a mere English boy who is only aware of Phoenix, Arizona and apparently bad at writing riddle stories as I think I included too much fluff for what should be extracted. If Gareth could cite Chris' comment in his answer then I'll mark it as correct and we can move on and pretend this never happened.

Comment: The size comparison was intended to symbolise that the USA (a country) is a lot bigger than Phoenix (a city)

Comment: OK, answer reorganized appropriately now.